# Sorting dictionary having list in python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a python dictionary, my code is below

```
d = {
 'r_18': {'text': u'INCOMET', 'center': [195.24393963813782, 521.3750743865967]},
'r_19': {'text': u'759R', 'center': [620.7350377559662, 1517.1044731140137]}
}

sorted_x = sorted(d.items(),key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=False)
sorted_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted_x)
print(sorted_dict)
```

I need a dict having ordered based on first and second value of list that should be ordered. ie, both the value containing list should be ordered like

the text value is in order based on ordered value of first y then x of list

> The error i got is TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of
>   'dict' and 'dict'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element of `d.items()` is a pair `(key, dict)` so if you want to use the list to sort you need to access and index it in the dict.
For instance, if you want to sort by `(y,x)` then the code becomes:

```
>>> sorted_x = sorted(d.items(),key=lambda kv: (kv[1]['center'][1],kv[1]['center'][0]) , reverse=False)
>>> sorted_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted_x)
OrderedDict([('r_18', {'text': 'INCOMET', 'center': [195.24393963813782, 521.3750743865967]}), ('r_19', {'text': '759R', 'center': [620.7350377559662, 1517.1044731140137]})])
```